# Raylib DrawTexture performance

Tags: go, fractals, raylib

I am wondering about performance in Raylib, especially using the `DrawTexture` and `NewImageFromImage` functions. I have the code below, it's written in Go so I am using the go-bindings found here : https://github.com/gen2brain/raylib-go

When I run the code below (full code : https://github.com/Hultan/fractal), I get approx. the following result for each frame:

```
Calculating done in 30.925822 ms!
Drawing done in 135.477039 ms!
```

So it calculates (and generates an image.Image) in 30 ms, and it takes four times as long to draw that image.

Am I using `Raylib` correct here? I have not tried to generate Mandelbrot fractals in decades, so those numbers might very well be reasonable today. I was expecting the computational part to be much slower than the drawing though, not the reverse...

And I do have a 5 year old graphics card, so maybe that's why...

```golang
const (
    width, height = 800, 600
)

func main() {
    rl.InitWindow(width, height, "fractal")
    defer rl.CloseWindow()

    img := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, width, height))

    for !rl.WindowShouldClose() {
        ...

        rl.BeginDrawing()

        t := time.Now()
        ...
        // Generating Mandelbrot fractal image into img
        ...

        fmt.Printf("Calculating done in %v!\n", time.Since(t))
        t = time.Now()

        tex := rl.LoadTextureFromImage(rl.NewImageFromImage(img))
        rl.DrawTexture(tex, 0, 0, rl.White)

        fmt.Printf("Drawing done in %v!\n", time.Since(t))

        rl.EndDrawing()

        rl.UnloadTexture(tex)
    }
}
```

Edit : Added information about the fractal size, see comment.

Comment: How big is this image? Uploading textures is generally an expensive operation, you want to do as little of that as possible. In any case I would expect logic like this to be doing the generation of images in a separate goroutine so a different core can be busying itself with that. When you see test results that look strange, usually the test itself is not optimal.

Comment: I am sorry, I cut that part of the code out. The image is 800x600...

The image is generated in a bunch of gouroutines, so that is not the problem (30ms).

The problem, in my opinion, is that it takes 130ms to draw an image in Raylib. I would have guessed that it would be much faster.